# Why can we deduce that $\psi$ exists? (i.e. does incompressibility imply irrotationality?)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

Fluid-dynamics. We have a 2D flow, incompressible. We need to show that $$\exists \psi(x,y,t)$$ such that $$u = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} ,\qquad v = -\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$$

**explanation in the book**

2D flow $\implies$ $q = (u,v,0)$ . Incompressible $\implies$ $\nabla \cdot q = 0 = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$

$\textit{hence, since we are in 2D, there must exists $\psi(x,y,t)$ such that}$ $$u = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}, \qquad v = -\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$$

Why can we conclude that there must exists a $\psi$ like that?

Comment: You can use `\qquad` and `\quad` to typeset horizontal spaces instead of chaining a lot of `\,`

Comment: @TZakrevskiy thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity $\partial_x u +\partial_yv = 0$ implies that a vector $(-v,u,0)$ is curl-free. Therefore, by Poincare's second lemma, this vector is a gradient.

Comment: how do you know it implies it is curl free? Incompressibility and irrotationality ($\nabla \cdot q = 0$ and $\nabla \times q = 0$ ) should be two independent conditions. Indeed we have examples of irrotational flows ($\nabla \times q = 0$) which are incompressible ($\nabla \cdot q = 0$) and vice versa.

Comment: Surely if you know it is curl-free, then you know there must be a potential function. However, at this stage we really don't know whether it's curl free or not

Comment: oh wait I know what you mean now! I didn't notice the minus sign! So yes it should work